# How to declare crossorigin="anonymous" globally with meta tag

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, cross-domain

How can i declare `crossorigin="anonymous"` with the help of meta tag?

```
<meta http-equiv="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" content="*" crossorigin="anonymous" />
```

OR

```
<meta name="crossorigin" content="anonymous">
```

Comment: The crossorigin attribute on an element specifies that CORS is supported when fetching files from a third-party server or domain. Elements that accept this attribute include <img>, <link>, <script>, <audio>, and <video>. So no current model accepts the crossorigin attribute in the meta tag. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/crossorigin

Comment: If you are using apache then you could probably set it on the header using .htaccess rules.  Have a look here  https://docs.nesez.com/2020/07/how-can-i-add-referrer-policy-header-in.html

Comment: Hi @EdgarReynaga , post this as answer, and I accept it :-)